# Susy: How to extend content box to cover grid-padding as well?

Tags: css, compass-sass, susy-compass

I just started to play with Susy. I have a 12 column grid that has grid-padding on it. Now i want the header of my page to span the whole grid including the grid-padding. What I'm doing right now is calculating the overall width and then setting a negative margin on the header. That's feels rather hacky to me... Is there a cleaner way to do it?

```
$total-columns  : 12;
$column-width   : 3.5em;
$gutter-width   : 1.25em;
$grid-padding   : 2em;

$total-width: ( $total-columns * ($column-width + $gutter-width) ) + ( 2 * $grid-padding ) - $gutter-width;

header {
    height: 150px;
    width: $total-width;
    margin-left: -$grid-padding;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two good options. One is a simplified version of what you have. Since block elements are 100% width by default, you can simply eliminate your width setting (and all that hacky math).

```
header {
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 - $grid-padding;
}
```

Your other option is to use multiple containers on the page. That requires a change to the markup, but sometimes it's a simplification that works well. If you move the header outside your current container, and declare it as a container of it's own, that will do the trick.

(as a side note: if you do need the full width ever, you can simply use the `columns-width()` function (for inner width, without padding) or `container-outer-width()` for the full width including the padding.)

**UPDATE:**

I've been using this mixin, to apply bleed anywhere I need it:

```
@mixin bleed($padding: $grid-padding, $sides: left right) {
  @if $sides == 'all' {
    margin: - $padding;
    padding: $padding;
  } @else {
    @each $side in $sides {
      margin-#{$side}: - $padding;
      padding-#{$side}: $padding;
    }
  }
}
```

Some examples:

```
#header { @include bleed; }
#nav { @include bleed($sides: left); }
#main { @include bleed($sides: right); }
#footer { @include bleed(space(3)); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically I did the right thing, since container-outer-width() does pretty much the same calculation I did. 
I have a few elements throughout the page that need to be full width so the container solution is no option here, but would be the cleanest if applicable I guess.
Leaving out the width though leaves the right padding of the container blank.

Comment: A negative right margin should handle the right padding just fine. The problem with `container-outer-width` is that it isn't percent-based, while the rest of your grid is. I would avoid setting fixed widths inside a Susy grid.

Comment: @EricMeyer I tried using this to get my grid element to bleed left and right, yet it only shifted the whole  container left.
I used
`#top-content {
 @include span-columns(24,24);
 @include border-radius($radius);
 @include bleed;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-top: 10px;
 height: 300px;
}`

And it shifted the box left.

Comment: @EricMeyer Actually, I was using new border-box include, that's why.  removed that and now it works right, at least in webkit.  Will this margin mixin work correctly in IE (7+)?

Comment: The Bleed mixin is now in Susy proper: http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-bleed