# SCSS & Susy: Makes boxes extend into grid gutters

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass

I have made a grid with the [excellent Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/).

I want to add a box the content in my grid. When I do this, everything gets cramped, as the box aligns to the same edge of the grid as the content.

I can add padding to the box and then apply box-sizing: border-box. This removes the 'cramping' but it also causes the content to no longer align to the gird.

What I would really like to do is keep the content aligned to the grid and have the box extend into the gutter. Is there a way to do this with Susy?

I have attached a graphic to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: Graphic Deminstrating problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution currently is to add negative margins equal to your padding.

See: [Susy: How to extend content box to cover grid-padding as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223927/susy-how-to-extend-content-box-to-cover-grid-padding-as-well)

We've added a more complex version of that same mixin to Susy ([here](https://github.com/ericam/susy/commit/33a3417cafa250a6c6cdf425737f2df82328cf3a)), but it hasn't been released in the gem yet.